# how to set the default value for postgresql DATE datatype - CURRENT_DATE is not working

Tags: node.js, postgresql, date, psql, pg

I'm using `pg` package in `node.js` and have created my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE clients_steps (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  client_id INTEGER NOT NULL
    REFERENCES clients ON DELETE CASCADE,
  step_id INTEGER NOT NULL
    REFERENCES steps ON DELETE CASCADE,
  update_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE 
);
```

Now I'm trying to seed my database. But it kept throwing errors at me.
My seed file:

```
### this works fine ###
INSERT INTO clients_steps (client_id, step_id, update_date)
VALUES (1, 2, '2023-02-02');

### this is not working ###
INSERT INTO clients_steps (client_id, step_id, update_date)
VALUES (1, 1);
```

And the error is:

> ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns than expressions
>
> > LINE 1: INSERT INTO clients_steps (client_id,step_id,update_date)

I think the reason is it can't insert the default value into the column.

So how should I set up the default value for a DATE datatype? I don't need the time stamp, only the date will be required.

Thank you so much!

Comment: `INSERT INTO clients_steps (client_id, step_id, update_date)
VALUES (1, 1, default)` or `INSERT INTO clients_steps (client_id, step_id)
VALUES (1, 1)`. The docs spell it out `DEFAULT`: *The default expression will be used in any insert operation that does not specify a value for the column. If there is no default for a column, then the default is null.*.  And [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) `DEFAULT`: *The corresponding column will be filled with its default value.*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to turn your second insert into valid SQL:

1. omit the column for which you want the default value from the list:

   ```
   INSERT INTO clients_steps (client_id, step_id)
   VALUES (1, 1);
   ```
2. use the special value `DEFAULT`:

   ```
   INSERT INTO clients_steps (client_id, step_id, update_date)
   VALUES (1, 1, DEFAULT);
   ```